# WPF C# for MacBook

Tags: c#, wpf, macos, visual-studio

My lecturer has started a new unit for WPF C# (.NET Core) as part of the software development course I am on. I use a MacBook Pro and have Visual Studio installed, however WPF does not appear to be available. Does anyone know how I can write WPF C# apps using a MacBook?

Comment: WPF is a technology which works on Windows only. If you can run Windows on your MacBook, or remote desktop into a Windows machine, you'll be OK, but you cannot develop WPF on macOS

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio for MacOS **does not support** developing WPF applications.

- [Visual Studio 2019 for Mac Platform Targeting and Compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs2019-compatibility-mac)
- [Comparision of Visual Studio for Mac and PC](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/) (scroll down)

WPF is a **Windows-only** framework, it does not run on MacOS or Linux and there are no plans to make it portable. You have to use Visual Studio (or of course any other IDE that is capable of creating WPF projects) for Windows, e.g. in a Virtual Machine. Ask your lecturer, if there are any *academic licenses* available, if you do not have access to a Windows PC.

Comment: I've been told to run windows on my MacBook via Parallel. Apparently, running VS there will allow me to complete the unit using the required WPF.

Comment: @MTW Yes, Parallels uses a virtual machine for Windows which will work.